# ggvis histogram tooltip with identification of elements in bins

Tags: r, tooltip, histogram, ggvis

I would like to create a tooltip on a ggvis histogram that would show the identification of the elements in that bin. An example:

```
id <- gl(100, 1)
value <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(id, value)
df %>% ggvis(~value) %>% layer_histograms
```

I would like a hover tooltip that would give the id of the values included in that bin, but i don't know how to get ggvis to give me this data to use in add_tooltip.

Thanks!

**Update:**

When using the tooltipFunc from r2evans bellow on a integer variable with cases for most integers, it would give ids duplicated on adjacent bin tooltips. To correct, just changed the inequality sign to reference left closed intervals (default in ggvis).

```
tooltipFunc <- function(index, value) {
  function(x) {
    if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
    else {
        paste(index[ (value >= x$xmin_ ) & (value < x$xmax_) ],
                  collapse=', ')
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw this feature demonstrated in RStudio's [webinar](http://pages.rstudio.net/Webniar-Series-Essential-Tools-for-R.html) this morning. Thanks for asking, I was meaning to learn about it anyway. The following is a bit of a hack, my first attempt at it, but it shows the ease and power of it:

```
tooltipFunc <- function(index, value) {
    function(x) {
        if (is.null(x)) return(NULL)
        else {
            strwrap(
                paste(index[ (value >= x$xmin_ ) & (value <= x$xmax_) ],
                      collapse=', '),
                width = 30)
        }
    }
}

df <- data.frame(id=gl(100,1), value=rnorm(100))
df %>%
    ggvis(~value) %>%
    layer_histograms() %>% 
    add_tooltip(tooltipFunc(df$id, df$value), 'hover')
```

This shows all `$id`s that are encompassed within a bin. In this case, the `x` (passed to the function) is a data.frame with one row and four columns: `$xmin_`, `$xmax_`, `$stack_upr_`, and `$stack_lwr_`. Because the function returns potentially literal HTML, it's not hard to take some liberties with this.

(This could have been done with a simpler function that presumed the presence of the `df` data.frame, but I thought it was slightly more extensible in this current form for future data sets.)

Comment: Arguably, something using a formula in place of fixed index/value pairings would be fairly robust and intuitive as well, moreso than this version.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that the tooltiptipfun could only take one argument, that would be the data.frame with four columns. But you could put that argument inside your function, and refer to data outside of it also (hehe, I can't yet understand how, but will look into it). Nice, worked perfectly on my real data. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, the function that is called from `add_tooltip` is only given one argument. I'm using the outer function to create the inner single-argument function that is actually passed to `add_tooltip`. I could also have just "reached outside" from inside the function to get at the data directly, but I generally don't like using that kind of variable scope if I can help it.